# is it possible to store the multiple phone number for a specific user without using loop in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have a relationship in laravel 5.4,

in User model

```
public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserPhone::class);
    }
```

in UserPhone model

```
public function user()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
```

now if from a form i got to input multiple phones record like:

```
<input type="text" name="phone[]">
<input type="text" name="phone[]">
<input type="text" name="phone[]">
```

so on then, 
 how can I store these phones for the particular user that has logged in currently in laravl5.4???

Comment: can you share your controller where you save phones ? You can simply create a model function as `saveUserPhones(array $phone_numbers)` and foreach inside there would be easiest solution or you can merge them and save as json inside database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$user = User::find($id) ;
$user->phones()->saveMany([
new UserPhone(['phone'=> Input::get('phone')[0] ]) ,
new UserPhone(['phone'=> Input::get('phone')[1] ]),
...
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$contact = [];
   foreach ($current_user_contact->phone as $key => $value) {
                array_push($contact, new UserPhone(['phone' => $value]));
   }
$current_user->phones()->saveMany($contact);
```

without for loop i could not find the way to solve it and had to go with above mentioned way.. And it is the same that is mentioned by [Milad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4477569/milad-teimoeri)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newUser = User::findOrFail(1);
    $phones = [
        ['phone' => '111111111'],
        ['phone' => '111111112'],
        ['phone' => '111111113'],
        ['phone' => '111111114'],
    ];

    foreach ($phones as $phone) {
        $phone = new UserPhone($phone);
        $phone->user()->associate($newUser);
        $phone->save();
    }
```